# Update a variable in list from another list using c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to copy data from one list to another list. While copying to the new list, i want to assign new values also. Can someone please assist quickly. I want to achieve something like below,

```
public HashSet<string> MobileNumber { get; set; }        
var contactViewData = MobileNumber.Select(p => p).SelectMany(o => o.SplitFromCsv()).Select(x => new ContactViewMap()
{
     ContactId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
     NewMobileNumber = x,
     OldMobileNumber = p
}).ToList();

public class ContactViewMap
{
    public string ContactId { get; set; }
    public string NewMobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string OldMobileNumber { get; set; }
}


public static IEnumerable<string> SplitFromCsv(this string csv)
            => csv.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.None);

Input:
{
  "MobileNumber": [
    "+9112352",
    "+9112353"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like a solution to the problem. Does it work? Is there something missing?

Comment: Actually it doesnt work. unable to retrieve values from ".Select(p => p)"

Comment: You have to show MobileNumber class at least. But better if you show all 3 classes

Comment: @Sergey Hope added information helps.

Comment: You have to show Csv fields then. You need a function that will split Csv into fields.

Comment: @Sergey Added input and SplitFromCsv() helper method

Comment: IMHO, Your helper should be like this public static IEnumerable<ContactViewMap> SplitFromCsv(this string csv).This i why I would like to see you csv line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227228/discussion-between-raj-and-sergey).

Comment: What do you expect `Select(p => p)` to do for you? The input you show isn't CSV - what does it have to do with the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select(p => p)` Just returns the same item again.

I think instead of this: `Select(p => p).SelectMany(o => o.SplitFromCsv())`
You need this: `Select(p => (p, csv: o.SplitFromCsv()) )`

Now you can use that tuple in the final `Select`:

```
.Select(x => new ContactViewMap()
{
     ContactId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
     NewMobileNumber = x.csv,
     OldMobileNumber = x.p
})
```